# Junk files created in place of deleted file

Tags: java, file, file-io, stream, delete-file

I have a strange problem. When I try to delete a file created by my application it gets deleted and gets replaced with a junk file of the exact same filesize. Can someone please help me out with this? Beats me. The same thing happens when I try to delete the file manually.

Comment: It's hard to help without more context.  Can you edit your question to add some of the code you're using?

Comment: Please provide some information on your operating system and post some of your code.

Comment: "..The same thing happens when i try to delete the file manually."  Sounds like it is a problem with your OS - nothing to do with Java.  BTW - did you have a question, or did you just want to share your troubles with us?

Answer (score 1):

are you perhaps using an NFS file system on linux? NFS will leave tombstones behind deleted files in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

(Unless you specify your operating system and post some of your code, this is pure guesswork.)

Since deleting the same file manually causes the same behaviour, it's reasonable to assume that this is not an issue with your code specifically.

Some filesystems (FUSE on Linux comes to mind, as well as some network filesystems) present this behaviour when deleting files that are in use by another process.